# Validate number with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I validate if the input in a text field is a number? `not_integer` is not what I am looking for. It can be a decimal number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check for `numericality`

```
validates :points, numericality: true
```

If you want a more general approach, you can use `is_a?`. The parent number class in Ruby is `Numeric`.

```
a = 4
a.is_a? Numeric
=> true

b = 5.4
b.is_a? Numeric?
=> true

c = "apple"
c.is_a? Numeric
=> false

d = "4"
d.is_a? Numeric
=> false
```

Comment: ok I thought it was necessary to use an attribute like `only_integer`. Also, what is the difference between `validates :whatever :numericality: true` and `validates_numericality_of :whatever`?

Comment: Just different styles of validating. Currently, it is considered better practice to use `validates` over `validates_numericality_of` because you can chain like validations. IE, `validates :age, presence: true, numericality: true`

Answer (score 1):

**To restrict the user from entering non-numeric values at the form-level and avoid expensive server call just to check numericality.**

Use this in the form:

```
<%= f.number_field :attribute_name, :step => 'any' %>
```

This will create an html element as below:

```
<input id="post_attribute_name" name="post[attribute_name]" step="any" type="number">
```

Upon form submission, the input value is checked at the form level. `step = "any"` will allow decimals.

I would also recommend adding validation at the Model level using,

```
validates :attribute_name, numericality: true  ## As suggested by Justin Wood
```

**This way you have double protection, i.e., one at the form-level itself and the other at Model level.**